Computational complexity of set cover problem with a fixed number of decision variables?
This paper show that integer programs with a fixed number of variables are solvable in time polynomial in the length of the data.
"In this section we show that the integer linear programming problem with a fixed value of $m$ is polynomially solvable. It was noted by P. van Emde Boas that this is an immediate consequence of our main result"
The wikipedia article also said the same about the author Hendrik Lenstra:"Developing an polynomial-time algorithm for solving a feasibility integer programming problem when the number of variables is fixed (in 1983);"
Does this means that set cover problem can be solved in polynomial time if the number of constraints increase and the number of decision variable are fixed ?
